# Why i can't create *.txt file in android?

Tags: java, android, file, directory

The below code creates a  `folder` :

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {
    private static final String DIR_SDCARD = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath();
    private static final String DIR_FILE = DIR_SDCARD + "/Android/data/com.project.google/Geo/";
    File myfile;
        myfile = new File(DIR_FILE+"GeoLocations.txt" );
        myfile.mkdirs();
}
```

But I need that `GeoLocations.txt` be `txt file` but it is folder when created.

Comment: java101: read the doc of the methods you are using.

Comment: You're making a folder called "GeoLocations.txt" because `mkdirs` makes folders along the entire path you concatenated, including the last entity. Cut "GeoLocations.txt" out from your path, call `mkdirs` and then open up a regular file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The line:

```
myfile.mkdirs();
```

Creates a directory based on the `File` object `myfile`.

If you wish to create a regular file, simply writing to `myfile` is sufficient, there is no need to call `mkdirs`.

If you are trying to create the directory that myfile will go into, then calling:

```
myfile.getParent().mkdirs()
```

Will do that.

Comment: When i remove myfile.mkdirs(); dont create any thing.

Comment: Java won't create your .txt file until you write something to it.

Answer (score 1):

it's creating the folder because you're asking it to create the folder with the `mkdirs()` command. What you want is:

```
myfile.getParent().mkdirs();
```

so it creates the parent folder from your file.